# Can't put an img as background. JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

EDIT: i fixed it with this:

```
.element{
 position: relative;
 top: 40%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 width:50%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 }
```

Ok, so i can't get it to work that i have an img as background on my page with jquery mobile.

I want an image as my background. But i can't figure it out.

So how can i make this work?

here's my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mobilethemes.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- allows to store on desktop for IOS -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

</head>
 <body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
     <h1>Header</h1> 
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="welcome">
    Here is my content
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
   <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
.ui-page, .ui-body-c, .ui-page-active, .ui-overlay-c, .ui-mobile-viewport
{
background: transparent !important;
}

body, .ui-overlay-c
{
background: url('../data/background.png') !important;
background-repeat:repeat-y !important;
background-position:center center !important;
background-attachment:scroll !important;
background-size:100% 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Is the path to the image file accurate?  Try looking at it in Chrome developer tools and see if the image is loading properly or if it gives you an error that it cannot resolve the path.

Comment: Yes, the img path is correctly.

Comment: Oh, you have quotes around the url. Remove those and I think it should work.

Comment: They are automaticaly put there. Tried removing but it's still the same.

Comment: How big is your image? I mean exact resolution.

Comment: I fixed it, check edit, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
 background-color: transparent;
```

of the children divs.

Comment: It fills the header and the footer with the img, but i want the background to be filled

Comment: Then add background-color: '#ffffff' for these divs